# Can i use the user defined regex in Meteor find function without escaping the special characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, meteor

I have a simple filter for searching images saved in a database. And therefore I use regex:
`Images.find({"name":{$regex:".*"+query+".*"}});`
Of course I check the value with `check(query, String);` function. **Could it be a big security issue, if I don't escape the special characters in the regex (query var, whose content is specified by user)?** It is an advantage for me, that the users can define something like (nameOfImage1|nameOfImage2).

Comment: And what if they define something like [`abc(.*)*def`](https://regex101.com/r/YVJUyt/2)?

Comment: In this case it does not find anything - but it isnt problem. I care only about the safety aspect.

Comment: With `abcdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddf` it will case a timeout.

Comment: Many search interfaces do a "contains" search on simple strings then have an option for the user to enter an explicit regex - those leading/trailing `.*`s could interfere with a power user's intent. From a security pov you are probably ok as the regex is being used in a `.find()` and not a `.update()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Michel Floyd´s comment above, that is not a security problem, I use Regex in `find()`. But I also replaced some selected characters with `query.replace(/[\/\\^$*[\]{}]/g, "");`